# IOS 8 extensions and use code of app target

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have adding share extensions and I want create custom UI for share. I want use my code which on app target. But when I try use classes that on app target, it show error "Unknown class **** in Interface Builder file" and many others. I know that this classes not adding to "share extension target". I few hours try to adding classes, header files and other to "share extension target".

I try to adding files to "Compile source, Link binary libraries, Copy bundle resources", setting "header search path", "prefix header"... The problem that I have, defines not find that in ".h" files which import in ".pch" file

Maybe there is a simple way to adding files on "share extension target"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I want use my code which on app target

You can't. The share extension and the app are *totally separate*. Your app is not running when the share extension runs, and the share extension can't "see" any of the app's code (or vice versa). You have two choices:

- Copy and paste. If you have code that you want to reuse, put that code into both places.
- Make an internal framework containing the common code and have both the share extension and the app import it. This is very well discussed in the WWDC 2014 videos on extensions (and there's one on frameworks).